# 'None Type' object has no attribute 'id' Hot to resolve Type Error

Tags: python, django

This is a medical inventory system.
Can't seem to get around this Type error. I am new to python and django.
I have looked at other similar errors but have not found a solution. here is my views.py file inside the home directory.

Kindly assist...thank you.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, Http404, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from accounts.models import Registration, YearEnding
from home.backup import BackupDatabase


@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
def HomePage(request):
   if not request.user.is_authenticated():
       raise Http404
   try:
   **  current_session_id = request.session['session'] **
   except:
   **  currentSession = YearEnding.objects.order_by("-id").first()   **
   **  request.session['session'] = currentSession.id      **
       current_session_id = currentSession.id

   current_session = get_object_or_404(YearEnding, id = current_session_id)
   return render(request, 'home/index.html', {"current_session":current_session})


@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
def takeBackup(request):
   if request.method == "GET" and request.is_ajax():
       forcefully = request.GET.get("forcefully")
       backup = BackupDatabase()
       response = backup.run(forcefully = int(forcefully))
       if response["code"] == 200:
           return JsonResponse(response, status=200)
       else:
           return JsonResponse(response, status=400)
    else:  
       return JsonResponse({}, status=400)
```

Comment: Does `currentSession = YearEnding.objects.order_by("-id").first()` exists?

Comment: No, I mean if the query actually return any result, because in other case it will return `None` and you'll get the type error.

Comment: Oh okay, i get it... No result returned. Its not even run to completion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#first):

> Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or None if there is no matching object.

Means if there is not `YearEnding` instance has been created, then `YearEnding.objects.order_by("-id").first()` will return `None`. So you need create one. You can do that from admin site, or shell. For example:

```
>> python manage.py shell
>> [python] from my_app.models import YearEnding
>> [python] YearEnding.objects.create(field1=value1,field2=value2)
```

One more suggestion, you can remove this code:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
   raise Http404
```

Because you are using `@login_required` decorator, it will automatically prevent non-logged in users from entering this view.

Comment: thanks a bunch. I have been able to resolve the error. quite simple now that its fixed.